# Creating text files from android app not visible in LG-D850

Tags: android, lg, android-internal-storage

I have created an android app that create text files and write in device local storage. Its working fine in all other devices, I can see created files in internal storage. However in LG-D850 (updated to android version 7.1) , the app working fine but not creating/showing files in internal storage. I have checked storage/emulated/0 but its not there.

Comment: What do you mean with "working fine in all devices"? Do these devices have another android version maybe?

Comment: @ZEESHAN Do you have runtime permission or just permissions in the manifest?

Comment: @cunnniemm Yes, I have permissions in the manifest. I tested my app in Samsung devices it is working fine on those devices.

Comment: @ZEESHAN Okay so one thing thats different in android 6 and up is that you have to use runtime permissions! Check answer

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are creating this file. Also, please explain exactly how you "checked storage/emulated/0" (`adb shell ls`? something else?)